# DateTime as key in a SortedDictionary<K, V>

Tags: .net, collections

Can I safely use `DateTime` as a key in a `SortedDictionary<K, V>` without implementing my own `IComparer`?

I've tried it and sort order is maintained and importantly for my purpose the `.ContainsKey<T>` method works as expected. But I just want to double check before committing myself down this road.

Comment: Do you use this at milliseconds level ? I am not able to make it work with milliseconds.

Comment: @Soundararajan - this was in a long since forgotten project, I don't remember the specifics any more. Perhaps ask a new question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you will not need a new IComparer.
your default IComparer will use the `Equals()` from your value object and compare/sort with that. Since the DateTime type implements the `Equals()` correctly, the default IComparer will sort as you want it to (like you have discovered).

creating new comparer's is more for complex collections that you may have written yourself. i wrote a complex comparer once. it's a bit mind blowing.

Comment: In a SortedDictionary<K, V> instantiated without passing a custom comparer Comparer<K>.Default is used to establish a sort order. Such a comparer does not call GetHashCode().

Comment: i think i meant .Equals()
my mistake

Answer (score 9):

I works well because `DateTime` implements `IComparable<DateTime>`. So you can rely in the [Comparer(T).Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx).

Internally, the `DateTime` uses ticks to compare 2 dates.

Answer (score 5):

I don't foresee any problems; behind the scenes the value is a long tick value.

Also, ensure that all of the values are based in the same time zone - personally I use UTC/GMT for storing and calculating and only adjust to local time when displaying.