# Removing the oldest item from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary

I'm working with a WPF application tasked with displaying a large amount of bitmap files. In the future I plan to implement a solution using vector graphics, but for now I have this problem:

To minimize the time my application reads files from disk I created a `Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>`  (where string is the file path of the image) to hold the most lately used images. If an image is requested that was recently viewed, the program fetches it from the `Dictionary` instead of from the disk. However, as the number of images viewed grows, so does the amount of RAM used by the program. So my idea was holding a limited amount of images, and as a new one is loaded from disk, overwrite the oldest one from my `Dictionary`.

How would I go about doing this in the best way possible? I've looked into using a `SortedDictionary` but can't figure out how to write an `IComparer` as neither the `keys` or `items` have any information about the time/order they were added.

Would keeping a separate `SortedDictionary<DateTime, string>` with a `DateTime IComparer` be a sensible solution? In that way, when a new file is added the path to the oldest added file can be found, and matched with the correct image in my `Dictionary`. This kind of feels like a to advanced solution though. Any overlooked or built-in solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [least recently used (LRU) cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used) ("discards the least recently used items first").  There are a few implementations floating around on the web:

- http://code.google.com/p/csharp-lru-cache/ (written by Bob Rossney)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/LRUCache.aspx (written by Brian Agnes)

Comment: I'll use the one by Bob Rossney. Better to use a good one than to make a mediocre one on my own ;P Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

IF you are on .NET 4 there is a built-in Cache mechanism - for a walkthrough see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997362.aspx

[It allows you to set conditions when the respective cached item is discarded etc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) and it allows for a callback in case an item is about to be removed (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx).

You can implement the caching policy you described (it is called [LRU - least recently used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used)) by using [CacheItemPolicy.SlidingExpiration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.slidingexpiration.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but we're on 3.5. I'll keep that in mind for further adventures though!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you make it easy for yourself and create a dictionary in a dictionary.

For example:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<string, Image>> SortedByDate;
```

I am unsure how and if a sorted dictionary sorts the dates correct, but if it does and the oldest equals the last entry you have it fairly easy to remove that entry.

Comment: This no longer allows you to search by path (string), though, does it?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that one! According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453124/datetime-as-key-in-a-sorteddictionaryk-v `DateTime` should work as a key.

Comment: @peachykeen Did not think about that! I'll look into it further.

Comment: @peachykeen: if you want to search for the path, it would make sense to store the inner dictionary in a second variable.

Comment: @AndreFly But then you would have multiple times for the same path, which should be the same image, and again defeats the purpose. Storing both is necessary, but you can't index by both in a nested fashion.

Comment: @peachykeen: I agree with you that you cannot index in a nested fashion, but as far as multiple storing goes I have to disagree. The object in the second dictionary is a pointer in the SortedByDate dictionary and the KEY to that object simply has to be updated to the current DateTime if you access it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against a dictionary, and instead use a List with a custom class that takes a bitmap, a string and a DateTime, something like:

```
public Class ImageLocation{
    public BitmapImage image;
    public string location;
    public DateTime timeLoaded;
}
```

Then you can use a `List<ImageLocation>` to store your images. Sort them by timeLoaded and then remove the one with the earliest DateTime.

That is, if you're not going to use the LRU cache for some reason.